# Trouble transferring photos from PC to iPad

Tags: ipad, photos, data-transfer, pc

I am trying to download photos from my Windows PC onto my iPad. I don't want to use iTunes. I am trying to download wirelessly. I used VLC app. I dragged my pictures into the designated area in the app. Each picture downloads and says 100% complete. A thumbnail of the picture never comes up it just says 100% in the spot the thumbnail should be. I can not find my photos anywhere on my iPad even after several attempts. I was only able to get 3 pictures to download onto my iPad. I waited a week and tried again this time nothing downloaded. I have also used several different transfer apps and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

On a Windows PC the iOS device may show up as a mountable volume. If you open Windows Explorer is your iPad there?

If so open it and look for a folder called Pictures (or similar, sorry it's been a while). If so you can just drag your pictures into that folder.

Granted iTunes is a beast but it makes transferring things between a computer and an iOS device so much easier. Is there a specific problem you are having with iTunes or do you just hate it because it's a bloated pile of inefficient code?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. My ipad was not in my Windows Explorer. I had onedrive on there so I opened onedrive in the ipad and it transferred the pictures. I heard to many horror stories about transferring with itunes so I just didnt want to do it that way. Thanks again!